# Problemas instalando paquetes ec2

Tags: aws, ec2

hola estoy intentando instalar unos paquetes en una instancia(ec2) siguiendo la documentacion([docu](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html)), pero cuando llego al paso en donde tengo que instalar paquetes como httpd24, php, etc con el comando `sudo yum install -y httpd24 php72 mysql57-server php72-mysqlnd`, me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He creado una instancia nueva pero aun nada.

Comment: Prueba `yum update`. Posiblemente le estás apuntando a repos donde esos paquetes no están. Si tampoco sirve, tienes líos de red. Si tu EC2 no tiene IP pública, no vas a poder conectarte a repositorios externos.

Comment: hola  @Alfabravo, mi instancia tiene ip publica menos mal jaja igual aplique sudo yum update -y antes de todo pero nada

Answer (score 0):

Para poder solucionar lo que hice fue seguir los siguientes pasos:

```
sudo su
yum update -y
yum install -y httpd
echo '<h1>Hello World</h1>' > /var/www/html/index.html
systemctl start httpd
systemctl enable httpd
```

Pero ademas, dentro de los security group agregue la inbound rule "http" y me conecte al dns sin el "https"